# Delete API - TriggerDeleteAPIPipeline.Run failed

Tags: api, apim

I'm currently having problems when trying to delete an API. Basically I followed all steps detailed here: https://cdas.azure.chevron.com/api-and-integration.wiki/API-Products/Delete-API-Utility.html. But when I hit the submit button at the last step It gives me this error here:

*TriggerDeleteAPIPipeline.Run failed: { "error": { "code": 502, "source": "msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net", "clientRequestId": "019d9dd4-976f-4bbd-9e4c-aac428af2577", "message": "BadGateway", "innerError": { "error": { "code": "NoResponse", "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id '08585506028467688679246934075CU94'." } } } }*

Any help on how to report this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue solved. The problem was that I needed to ask for the Personal access token in "full access scope".